# Nginx + lua Как правильно парсить Json

Tags: json, веб-программирование, nginx, lua

server{

```
            server_name api;
            listen 8082;
            lua_need_request_body on;
            location  /json/add/{
                root /home/ivan/json/ ;
                 access_by_lua_block{
                    local cjson = require("cjson")
                    ngx.req.read_body()
                    local text = ngx.var.request_body
                    local value = cjson.new().decode(text)
                    ngx.say(text)
                    ngx.say(type(value))
                    ngx.say(table.getn(value))
                    for k,v in ipairs(value) do
                        ngx.say(k)
                        ngx.say(table.getn(v))
                        for _, vv in ipairs(v) do
                            ngx.say(_)
                            ngx.say(vv)
                        end
                    end
                }
            }

}
```

посылаю запрос
 curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '[ {"username":"xyz"},{"password":"xyz"} ]' http://localhost:8082/json/add/

ответ

[ {"username":"xyz"}, {"password":"xyz"} ] table 
2 
1 
0 
2 
0

Как получить значения username, password?

Answer (score 2):

Метод `table.getn()` (кстати, вместо него [нужно пользоваться оператором `#`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#7.2)) работает только с "настоящими" массивами (с числовыми ключами). Получить `username` можно так: `v["username"]` или `v.username`

Или заменить во внутреннем цикле `ipairs` на `pairs`:

```
for kk, vv in pairs(v) do
  ngx.say(kk)
  ngx.say(vv)
end
```